# Simultaneously Executing multiple PL SQL Blocks

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a need where in I have several blocks/functions that need to be executed simultaneously; I cant do them sequentially as sleep function would be involved and that will take a lot of time. Please advice.

```
**Pseudo Code:**
begin
loop outer
begin
     do x;
     sleep (3 sec);
     do y;

end;

begin

     do Z;
     sleep (3 sec);
     do A;

end;
end outer loop
end;
```

Comment: They will never be perfectly sequential as different PL/SQL blocks cannot interact with each other. The standard way would be to start a background job but I think it would be better if you explained _why_ you wanted to do this and maybe someone can come up with a far better solution that removes this need.

Comment: [This might help](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4712493580500), but as Ben said, your motivation needs to be clear before you jump to a solution.

Comment: well forgive me for that.

I want to check for the count of rows in several different tables (as much as 15) on the interval of 300 sec (5 mins). these count represent incoming transactions. one option would be the use of shell scripts and nohup. but i was wondering if i can define these queries in individual functions/named blocks/procedures and execute them simultaneosly and restrict this script to  database only. 
The point of doing this is to find out if @ any given instance my transaction count is the same.

Comment: Alex.. m giving ur link a try... thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through `parallel_enable` and `pipelined` clause, as a good source of info I offer you Ask Tom and ofcourse Stackowerflow))